# How mutex semaphore works?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, multicore

I am trying multi-core programming, to implement **Mutex** semaphore for :
**Initialization; Request ownership; Release ownership; Try ownership; Destruction .**

I've created 3 threads. Each thread operates on a global variable  Answer. 9 out of 10 times threads execute sequentially. But sometimes thread 3 didn't execute. Is 2nd threads mutex didn't release ?

Here's My Code: thread_tasks.cc

```
void *task1(void *X)
{

    int MValue = pthread_mutex_init(&Mutex,NULL); //Initialization
    pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex); //Request ownership
    Answer = Answer * 32; //critical section
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex); //Release ownership
    flag1=1;
    cout << "\nthread A Answer = " << Answer << endl;
    cout<<"\nthread 1 executed successfully";
}

 void *task2(void *X)
 {
    if(flag1==1)
 {
    int RC = pthread_mutex_trylock(&Mutex); //Try ownership
    cout<<"\nRC: "<<RC;
    Answer = Answer/2;
    flag2=1;
    cout<<"\nthread 2 executed successfully";
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex); //Release ownership
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&Mutex); //Destruction

}
}



void *task3(void *X)
{
    Answer = Answer+5;
    cout<<"\nthread 3 executed successfully";
}
```

Header file: thread_tasks.h

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

void *task1(void *X);
void *task2(void *X);
void *task3(void *X);
```

mutex_example.cpp

```
int Answer = 10;
int flag1 = 0;
int flag2 = 0;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

 pthread_t ThreadA, ThreadB, ThreadC;

 cout << "Answer = " << Answer << endl;
 pthread_create( &ThreadA,NULL,task1,NULL);
 pthread_create( &ThreadB,NULL,task2,NULL);
 pthread_create( &ThreadC,NULL,task3,NULL);
 pthread_join(ThreadA,NULL);
 pthread_join(ThreadB,NULL);
 pthread_join(ThreadC,NULL);

 cout << "Answer = " << Answer << endl;

 return(0);
}
```

Comment: You have a data race on `flag1` and `flag2`. It doesn't help that you write them under the protection of a mutex, when you read them without.

Comment: Also, data race aside, your code does't ensure that threads execute sequentially. It instead ensures that, if a thread `N+1` happens to run ahead of thread `N`, it simply does nothing, skipping all substantial processing. You don't have any logic that makes thread `N+1` to wait for thread `N` to complete.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If I don't use flags the answer sometimes becomes 162 because thread 3 executes before thread 2 what should be the logic for sequential execution?

Comment: Firstly, clean up your code and reduce it to the bare minimum but complete example as required by the site rules. Then, make sure you always document which data is protected by which mutex and never access that data without holding the mutex. Getting this correct should be the biggest step to a correct program.

Comment: if you have c++11 or better, use `std::mutex` and `std::thread`. No need to play with pthread code directly at all.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Is it okay now?

Comment: @RichardHodges I want to implement using pthread

Comment: It's not okay yet. The minimal example shouldn't take more than a single file. I gues you don't need more than two threads, currently you have four. Your code isn't indented consistently. `Mutex` is undeclared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue:
 Used thread_1done and thread_2done for maintaining sequence.

```
void *task1(void *X)
     {
        int MValue = pthread_mutex_init(&Mutex,NULL); //Initialization
        pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex); //Request ownership
        Answer = Answer * 32; //critical section
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex); //Release ownership
        thread_1done=1;
        cout << "\nthread A Answer = " << Answer << endl;
        cout<<"thread 1 executed successfully"<<endl;
     }


    void *task2(void *X)
    {
        while(1)
            if(thread_1done==1)
            {
                int RC = pthread_mutex_trylock(&Mutex); //Try ownership
                Answer = Answer/2;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex);
                thread_2done=1;
                cout << "\nthread B Answer = " << Answer << endl;
                cout<<"thread 2 executed successfully"<<endl;
                break;
            }
    }



    void *task3(void *X)
    {
        while(1)
            if (thread_2done==1 && thread_1done == 1)
            {
                int RC = pthread_mutex_trylock(&Mutex); //Try ownership
                Answer = Answer+5;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex);
                pthread_mutex_destroy(&Mutex); //Destruction
                cout << "\nthread C Answer = " << Answer << endl;
                cout<<"thread 3 executed successfully"<<endl;
                break;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the real execution of thread 3 function - task3 need flag2==1, which at that time maybe thread 2 has't finished the flag2 reset task. So task 3 is likely not into the *if* block.